# Use of address function inside a contract constructor?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solid

Wondering if anyone can explain this. I am following along in the "Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract Course - Beginner to Expert Python Tutorial" by freeCodeCamp.org.

In lesson two we create a contract factory in which we store an array of contracts and then create a function to retrieve the contract by index and call a function on it.

Here is how he did it: `SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorages[_simpleStorageIndex])).store(_simpleStorageNumber)`

I do not understand the SimpleStorage(address(...)) part. I understand indexing into the array and getting the storage, but I tested it and this works the same: `simpleStorages[_simpleStorageIndex].store(_simpleStorageNumber)`

What is this address function? I assume it gets the address of the contract instance. Then why do we pass it to a constructor(?) of SimpleStorage? Why do all this when calling store on the instance itself without going through addresses works.

Thanks!!

EDIT: Entire contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

contract StorageFactory is SimpleStorage { // is SimpleStorgae = inheritance 

    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorages;

    function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorages.push(simpleStorage);
    }

    function sfStore(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex, uint256 _simpleStorageNumber) public {
        // Anytime you interact with a contract you need two things:
        // Address
        // ABI - Application Binary Interface
        return simpleStorages[_simpleStorageIndex].store(_simpleStorageNumber);
        //return SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorages[_simpleStorageIndex])).store(_simpleStorageNumber);
    }

    function sfGet(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex) public view returns(uint256) {
        return SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorages[_simpleStorageIndex])).retrieve();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you enclose the entire text of the contract?

Comment: Updated with full contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach, calling the `store()` function right on the item, is in fact a more straightforward way to achieve the same result as the lecturer's code.

So to answer your questions:

> *What is this address function? I assume it gets the address of the contract instance.*

Correct. Even though the `simpleStorages[_simpleStorageIndex]` doesn't store the actual `SimpleStorage` instance. Within your contract, it only stores a helper object that contains a pointer to the external contract address, as well as interface definition of the `SimpleStorage` (but not the actual instance of the external contract).

Typecasting the helper object to an `address` returns the address of the external contract.

> *Then why do we pass it to a constructor(?) of SimpleStorage*

You're not passing it to the `SimpleStorage` constructor - that would be `new SimpleStorage(<constructor_params>)` with the `new` keyword (effectively deploying the `SimpleStorage` contract to a new address). You're instantiating the helper object described above, passing it the external contract address.

> *Why do all this when calling store on the instance itself without going through addresses works.*

I don't know the lecturer's intentions behind this code. Maybe they use it later in the course to describe some optimization or as a bridge to show some other topic. But both ways work.